# Angular 6: access "this" in catch => errHandler

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

### My Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { _log, notice, SnotifyService } from '../utils';


@Injectable()
export class ConfigsService {

    constructor( public notice: SnotifyService )  {}

    addProductModifier(data) {
        this.notice.warning(show); // works finf
        return this.http.get<any>( api_url + '/addProductModifier', {params: data} ).catch(this.errHandler);
    }

    errHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        let show = error.error.formatted || error.statusText;
        _log(show, 'e');
        this.notice.warning(show); // Cannot read property 'warning' of undefined
        return Observable.throw(error.error || "unknown error");
    }

}
```

### Question

In the above code you can see that `this` is not available in the errHandler function. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try `.catch(this.errHandler.bind(this))` or use an arrow function.

Comment: @connorsFan make that an answer so i can upvote

Comment: I suggest confirming that the question is a duplicate. This question is asked every day on the Angular forum. :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `errHandler` to `catch` you are only passing the function not its associated `this`. `this` will be decided by the caller (in this case the observable). This is the way functions behave in Javascript, even class methods are not tied to a specific object instance.

The simplest solution is to transform `errHandler` to an arrow function ( `=>`) which captures `this` from the declaration context:

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigsService {

    constructor( public notice: SnotifyService )  {}

    addProductModifier(data) {
        this.notice.warning(show); // works finf
        return this.http.get<any>( api_url + '/addProductModifier', {params: data} ).catch(this.errHandler);
    }

    errHandler = (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        let show = error.error.formatted || error.statusText;
        _log(show, 'e');
        this.notice.warning(show); // Cannot read property 'warning' of undefined
        return Observable.throw(error.error || "unknown error");
    }

}
```

You could also use `bind` when you pass the function to `catch`

```
addProductModifier(data) {
    this.notice.warning(show); // works finf
    return this.http.get<any>( api_url + '/addProductModifier', {params: data} ).catch(this.errHandler.bind(this));
}
```